# How can I replace a textview with a button?

Tags: android

How can I remove a textview and replace it with a button with the same text and the same position?
I need to do that programatically when I press another button in the activity.

Comment: In the same Layout where you defined the TextView, define a Button with the same atributes for size, alignment and position if needed depending on the type of the Layout and set its visibility to `gone`. When you click the other Button, set the TextView's visibility to `gone` and the Button's to `visible`.

Comment: Add your xml layout file, so I can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_test_one"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Lorem Ipsum"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_test_one"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Lorem Ipsum"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

There are TextView and Button both at same position.

Now you need to do is:

```
TextView tv_test_one = findViewById(R.id.tv_test_one);
Button btn_test_one = findViewById(R.id.btn_test_one);

// This will replace button to textview
tv_test_one.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
btn_test_one.setVisibility(View.GONE);

//This will Replace TextView to Button
tv_test_one.setVisibility(View.GONE);
btn_test_one.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```